# Finding out with which parameters a program was started

Tags: linux, process

Is there a way to find out for any given process with which parameters it was started?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find what arguments were passed to pdnsd, I'd do:

```
[~]> pgrep -l pdnsd
1373 pdnsd
[~]> cat /proc/1373/cmdline 
/usr/sbin/pdnsd--daemon-p/var/run/pdnsd.pid[~]>
```

(`cmdline` file entries are separated by null characters; use something like `tr '\0' '\n' </proc/<pid>/cmdline` to see more legible output.)

`/proc/<pid>/`  contains a lot of information.

Comment: Note that the command line *can* be overwritten by the program itself; certain pieces of software do this for benign reasons, usually to put useful human-readable information in the `ps` output, but also malign reasons like an exploit or rootkit trying to hide itself.

Comment: Way too complex. Why not just `pgrep -a pdnsd`?

Answer (score 4):

For Linux, `ps -ef` yields the whole command line including the parameters.

For Solaris, things could be more problematic but you tagged the question with Linux...